# Android SDK Zip archive

Tags: android, sdk

I tried installing the android SDK from the installer provided but it says: "JDK not found". However, I have the latest version of JDK installed. I also made an environment variable pointing to it by going to "Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment variables > New System Variable > Name: JAVA_HOME > Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin.

When I type javac on my command prompt, it works just fine. 
javac -version yields: javac 1.7.0_5

After googling I saw some people installing the SDK via the zip archive. I downloaded and extracted that. There's a .exe called "SDK Manager.exe". I click it and nothing happens. The  command prompt flashes for a quick sec and disappears. That's it. Any solution?

Comment: Run sdk manager from cmd and post the output.

Comment: No output.. Just nothing.. Anyway I solved it now.. I needed to add my JDK location to the path variable BEFORE the system32\ variable..

Answer (score 1):

You have added a System Environment variable JAVA_HOME, which is fine.

You also need to add the %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the PATH variable. And launch a fresh command window from where you can try out "SDK Manager.exe"